# How to extract 36 values from VARRAY in table and display as 3 consecutive years (12 months each)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

** Edited to add month

In our (ORACLE 11G) database we have a table that has a custom data type that is a VARRAY with 32 values (Integers).  These numbers represent a value for each month of a year for 3 consecutive years.  In the same record,there will be a work year.  This work year will always be the middle year of the VARRAY's relative years.  I'm trying to figure out a way to display these as such:

Current:

```
| ID   | WORK_YEAR | PRODUCTION |
| 2127 |   2012    |[1..36] (<--I'm just doing 1 through 36 for simplicity's sake)
```

My desired output would be something like this:

```
|  ID   |  WORK_YEAR    |    MONTH   | PRODUCTION
| 2127  |     2011      |   JANUARY  |    1
| 2127  |     2011      |  FEBRUARY  |    2
| 2127  |     2011      |    MARCH   |    3
...
...
| 2127  |     2012      |   JANUARY  |   13
| 2127  |     2012      |  FEBRUARY  |   14
...
...
| 2127  |     2013      |  JANUARY   |   25
| 2127  |     2013      |  FEBRUARY  |   26
...
...
| 2127  |     2013      |  DECEMBER  |   36
```

My end goal would be to pivot it and have a column for each month and then a record for each ID, YEAR; however, I can't figure out how to get it to this format first.

So far I've only got:

```
SELECT
    WP.ID,
    WP.WORK_YEAR,
    PRO.COLUMN_VALUE AS PRODUCTION
FROM
    LINEWORK.WORK_PRODUCTION WP,
    TABLE(WP.PRODUCTION) PRO
;
```

But this doesn't let me make the year relative on the index of PRODUCTION that I'm accessing.  Any and all insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the correct results by suing case statements and then pivoting the data as seen below:

```
select * from
(
select
    WP.ID CR_ID,
    case
        when row_number() over(partition by WP.ID order by 1) < 14 then to_char(to_number(WP.WORK_YEAR, '9999') - 1)
        when row_number() over(partition by WP.ID order by 1) > 25 then to_char(to_number(WP.WORK_YEAR, '9999') + 1)
        else to_char(to_number(WP.WORK_YEAR))
    end WORK_YEAR,
    PRODUCTION.COLUMN_VALUE PRODUCTION,
    case
        when row_number() over(partition by WP.ID order by 1) - 1 < 13 then row_number() over(partition by WP.ID order by 1) - 1
        when row_number() over(partition by WP.ID order by 1) - 13 > 0 then
            case
                when row_number() over(partition by WP.ID order by 1) - 13 < 13 then row_number() over(partition by WP.ID order by 1) - 13
                else row_number() over(partition by WP.ID order by 1) - 25
            end
    end MNTH
from
    LINEWORK.WORK_PRODUCTION WP,
    table(WP.PRODUCTION) PRO
)
pivot
(
    sum(PRODUCTION)
    for MNTH in 
    (
    0 TOTAL,
    1 JANUARY,
    2 FEBRUARY,
    3 MARCH,
    4 APRIL,
    5 MAY,
    6 JUNE,
    7 JULY,
    8 AUGUST,
    9 SEPTEMBER,
    10 OCTOBER,
    11 NOVEMBER,
    12 DECEMBER
    )
)
order by 
    ID, 
    WORK_YEAR
;
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Oracle very well, I googled some things about Oracle VARRAY and so try this >>

```
SELECT
    WP.ID,
    WP.WORK_YEAR,
    WP.PRODUCTION.COUNT AS maxMonth,
    PRO.X AS MonthNdx,
    (TRUNC(PRO.X / 12, 0) - 1) AS adjYear,
    WP.WORK_YEAR +  (TRUNC(PRO.X / 12, 0) - 1) AS TrueYear,
    PRO.COLUMN_VALUE AS PRODUCTION
FROM
    LINEWORK.WORK_PRODUCTION WP,
    TABLE(WP.PRODUCTION) PRO
;
```

Revised, remove PRO.X, use ROW_NUMBER() >>

```
SELECT
    WP.ID,
    WP.WORK_YEAR,
    WP.PRODUCTION.COUNT AS maxMonth,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By WP.ID  Order By 1) AS ArrayNdx,
    --PRO.X AS MonthNdx,
    (TRUNC(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By WP.ID  Order By 1) / 12, 0) - 1) AS adjYear,
    WP.WORK_YEAR +  (TRUNC(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By WP.ID  Order By 1) / 12, 0) - 1) AS TrueYear,
    PRO.COLUMN_VALUE AS PRODUCTION
FROM
    LINEWORK.WORK_PRODUCTION WP,
    TABLE(WP.PRODUCTION) PRO
;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  I was able to restructure the count syntax and get the count of total months; however, Oracle isn't recognizing the 'PRO.X' part.  It just says invalid identifier.  I will keep looking into this though.  Thanks for the idea!

Comment: @eikago can you look at the definition of the WP.PRODUCTION array, and see what its index is named?